# How to change color of words in Gedit?

Tags: colors, cuda, gedit

I'm writing a code in CUDA C and I'm using Gedit as text editor; when I type some functions like sizeof(), the editor does not color them. In simple words this is what I would like to see:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main(){

int a = sizeof(int);
return 0;  
}
```

This is instead what i get: `sizeof()` not colored!! What should i do to modify the color of the function? i have already installed all the plug-in but I don't know what else to do...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

CUDA is included by default so simply switch from plain text to CUDA (or any other language) on the right lower part of the window or using the general menu options:

See -> Highlight mode -> CUDA

Gedit uses GtkSourceView for syntax highlight, so you can define your own language if you want. Gedit doesn't highlight some functions like `sizeof` but still you can add them on the cuda.lang file:

```
locate gtksourceview | grep /cuda.lang
```

This [link](https://developer-old.gnome.org/gtksourceview/stable/lang-tutorial.html) has more information about the definition of a language via .lang files.

EDIT: the c language does include the definition of `sizeof`, so this should be useful for CUDA, search for `keyword` on the link!

Comment: Nope... unfortunately i had already tried that...  I'm working in cuda mode... but nothing happens... it won't color some of the functions and i was wandering if i could color them myself

Comment: ahhh!! ok now i will give a shot

Comment: You can find everything you need on the link!